# Why doesn't my typescript compiler work correctly?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, node-modules, tsc

I just reinistalled windows and wanted to code a bit, while i was trying to compile typescript to a node module (.js file) the typescript compiler didn't output the correct code.
i'll give an example:

```
import { Size } from "./Utils/Size";

export class Canvas {
    private canvasElement: HTMLCanvasElement;
    private context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

    public constructor(options: CanvasOptions) {
        let c: HTMLCanvasElement;
        if (options.customCanvasId)
            c = document.getElementById(options.customCanvasId) as HTMLCanvasElement;
        else
            c = document.createElement("canvas");
    }

}

export interface CanvasOptions {
    isResizable: boolean;
    minResolution: Size;
    maxResolution: Size;
    customCanvasId?: string;
}
```

This wil compile to:

```
export class Canvas {
    constructor(options) {
        this.c = document.createElement("canvas");
        let c;
        if (options.customCanvasId)
            c = document.getElementById(options.customCanvasId);
        as;
        HTMLCanvasElement;
    }
}
```

and the compile errors give me:

```
Canvas.ts(10,56): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Canvas.ts(10,59): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Canvas.ts(11,3): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
Canvas.ts(15,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

If i look at my code, everything is oke for my part so why doesn't it output correctly?

p.s.
My tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions":
    {
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "../react-engine/src/engine-core"
    }
}
```

I tried to format the code but it helped nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Oke so after 2 min i found out i did a `npm i tsc` instead of `npm i typescript` ...

i feel so dumb...